# CouldNotFindModuleError on Google App Engine and Python 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

There is another question on this but i didn't found it useful.

I've installed Google App Engine SDK 1.7 with Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

When i launch the app from the Google App Engine Launcher, i have this error in the logs

```
CouldNotFindModuleError
```

the entire log is here:

http://pastebin.com/EwbpMcx2

**ok it could not find a module, but what module?** how can i solve this?

my app is very simple, a hello world

**app.yaml**

```
application: alleudacity
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: no
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

**helloword.py**

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using libraries elixir and paramiko which are not available by default on google app engine.

You can either not use them (good way to test if that's really the problem), or potentially if they are pure python libraries, install them in your actual project folder.

When you deploy to app engine, only files in your project folders are uploaded - libraries that installed elsewhere in your system won't be available.  dev_appserver modifies your environment so that you see these failures locally, rather than having things work fine locally and break after you deploy.

Comment: thanks for explanation. What if i don't use them but i want them installed on system for other project, isn't there a way to tell google app engine: "don't use these libraries"?

Comment: Having them installed on your system is no problem.  The problem is that you're using (ie importing it).  If you're not directly importing those guys, you might be using some other library that is.

Comment: but i don't import anything atm.. look at the helloworld.py, it's all the code i have. 
i've removed paramiko and elixir eggs (which gave me the warnings), ma i have the same error

Answer (score 1):

I guess I misread the trace.  You're missing some module.  Looking at the google code, it should print out the name of the module you're missing.  But since I don't see it, you could force a breakpoint right before where the error should be and see what the name of the missing module is.  Force a breakpoint by editing the code (C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py) and adding

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```